# Need to know about ENUM for contact in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, enums, sprite-kit

I tried to make contact but it didn't work .

I create an enum:

```
enum object:UInt32{
    case BB = 1
    case TR = 2
    case GAP = 3
}
```

Then I have 3 nodes:

```
balloon.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = object.BB.rawValue
balloon.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = object.TR.rawValue
balloon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = object.GAP.rawValue

tree2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = object.TR.rawValue
tree2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = object.BB.rawValue

gap.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = object.GAP.rawValue
gap.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = object.GAP.rawValue
gap.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = object.BB.rawValue
```

In DidBeginContact:

```
let result = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask + contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

switch result{
    case object.BB.rawValue + object.TR.rawValue:
        xoaBB(contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode, TR: contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode, toaDo: contact.contactPoint)

    case object.BB.rawValue + object.GAP.rawValue:
        score++
        scorelabel.text = "\(score)"

    default:
        return
    }
```

The problem is:

```
"case object.BB.rawValue + object.GAP.rawValue" didn't work
```

I want the ballon fly through the gap to score but it can't. Balloon just  contact to gap and gets stuck there as shown here.

[image]

Can anyone help me, I really need "how to use Enum tutorial too"

Comment: First thing is to consider the fact that the bit masks are, well, bit masks. Values 1, 2 & 3 are not making sense since the sum of the first two equals the value of the third. Values should be 1,2,4,8 etc.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment your bitmask-values doesn't quite make sense. How about something a little like this (I have not checked for typos):

```
enum MaskType : UInt32 {
    case Balloon = 1
    case Gap = 2
    case Wall = 4
    case None = 0
}
```

Then you need to decide what you are after. The following example does not register collisions, meaning you want have physical interactions happening between the objects.

```
balloon.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = MaskType.Balloon.rawValue
balloon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = MaskType.None.rawValue
balloon.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = MaskType.Gap.rawValue | MaskType.Wall.rawValue
```

The balloon sprite will now register contacts with objects having either the .Gap or .Wall value as their categoryBitMask.

If you now setup your other spriteNode's physicsBodies appropriately you can do some nice things in the `didBeginContact` function. Perhaps something like this:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactA = contact.bodyA
    let contactB = contact.bodyB

    func ballonHitType() -> Uint32 {
       if contactA.categoryBitMask == MaskType.Baloon.rawValue {
           return contactB.categoryBitMask
       } else {
           return contactA.categoryBitMask
       }
    }

    // Then simply perform your wanted actions based on whatever ballonHitType you receive
}
```